# Is it possible to automatically take zfs snapshots on boot or shutdown?

Tags: linux, backup, zfs, zfsonlinux

I want to create a convenient solution for full system (root-on-ZFS) backups.
The idea is to create a snapshot of the whole system on startup (before any writes to FS) or as a last step of shutdown process. That way I want to guarantee, that the FS is *logically* consistent, i.e. the snapshot represents the state of the cold FS (without any unfinished processes).
Later this snapshot can be backed up with `zfs send` to another location, if necessary.

Again, the idea is to guarantee, not that just all I/O operations are finished and consistent, but that all processes finished, so the FS state is globally and logically consistent.
For instance, it is impossible, that some program has written file `a` and it got into snapshot, but finished writing to file `b` a microsecond later, so file `b` is not present in the snapshot, while for program operation it is necessary, that the files are in sync.

EDIT: my distro is Arch Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach your requirements is to create the snapshot during boot from the initrd (aka initramfs) before any processes which may write to the filesystem start. (Assuming this is a "normal" Linux installation that uses an initrd.) Unfortunately you don't mention which Linux distribution you are using so I can't offer you more specific advice on how to add your own step to the initrd because different distributions do it differently. For example, on Arch Linux and derivatives you would create a custom mkinitcpio hook in /etc/initcpio/hooks and add it to the "hooks" line in your /etc/mkinitcpio.conf file (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/mkinitcpio). Your custom hook would simply create the snapshot after the ZFS pool has been imported so that it is created before the initrd has passed control to the regular system startup process. Other distributions have other methods of adding steps to the initrd.

Some advice: When asking Linux questions, it's a very good idea to give more detail than you've given here. Most importantly, you should mention the Linux distribution that you are using. It's also a good idea to add in as much general information about your system as you can think of just in case it might be helpful for someone attempting to answer your question. For questions about filesystems things like your disk partition table type (DOS or GPT), disk partitions that may be relevant, whether you using any form of RAID or mirroring, whether you are using encryption of any sort, whether you are using LVM etc. might be helpful. For your specific question, additional information such as whether you have multiple filesystems with multiple mountpoints in your pool and whether you are using ZFS's automounting or legacy mounting would also be helpful. Hope this helps!

Comment: (btw) I use arch, updated the question